# Carbon create date trailing data error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-carbon

I'm trying to create a carbon date as follows to store in a timestamp column:

```
 'from_dt' => Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', Carbon::now()->year . '-04-01'),
 'to_dt' => Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', Carbon::now()->addYear() . '-03-31'),
```

But I'm getting an `[InvalidArgumentException] Trailing data` exception.

In my model I have set the protect dates property as follows:

```
// ensure dates are accessed and set as a date
protected $dates = ['from_dt', 'to_dt'];
```

What the correct way to set a date using carbon and how can I automatically work out the to_dt one year from the from_dt - currently I'm having to hard code the day and month of the to_dt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to fix it. Solution below.

```
'from_dt' => Carbon::parse(Carbon::now()->year . '-04-01'),
'to_dt' => Carbon::parse(Carbon::now()->addYear()->year . '-03-31'),
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also same issue . i was using wrong format.
Now it is fix by following code

```
$dob                          = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $input['date_of_birth']);

$input['date_of_birth']       = $dob->format('Y-m-d');
```